# JSP Pages of Tomcat 5.5 in not loading/rendering properly when deployed in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, war

I have to migrate my project from Tomcat 5.5 to Tomcat 6. In this process I have compiled my project against [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment) 6. Initially it was in JRE 5. And I have copied the project into Tomcat web applications.

However, my webpages are not loading and the strange thing is I do not get any error in Tomcat logs. I get a blank white page.

What can be the reason? Is there a solution?

**EDIT**

1. I am accessing the jsp page directly
2. The Server starts successfully and no error in catalina log. Also no error in stdout.log

Comment: Too little information is contained in the question... Is your project using any MVC framework? Are you accessing the JSPs directly (i.e. http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/myjsp.jsp)? What is in your catalina log when the server starts?

Comment: Can you show us your JSP and possibly `web.xml`? You can also check the compiled page in `${catalina.home}/work/Catalina/localhost/yourwebapp/org/apache/jsp/...`.

Comment: One additional question: Why Tomcat 6 and not the latest stable Tomcat 8?